# Swift: Setting the height and width of buttons has no effect

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, tvos

I have this tabBar, created programmatically:
[image]

```
func createTabBar() {
       var arrangedSubviews = [UIView]()
       if let menus = CMSessionManager.sharedInstance.menus {
           for menu_item in menus {
               if let menuInfoDetails = menu_item as? [String: Any] {
                   let tabButton = CustomButton(color: .red, titleString: menuInfoDetails["label"] as! String)
                   // This apparently has no effect on button size
                   tabButton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)
                   arrangedSubviews.append(tabButton)
               }
           }
           stackView.alignment = .leading
           stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrangedSubviews)
           stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
           stackView.axis = .horizontal
           stackView.spacing = 8
           self.view.addSubview(stackView)
           stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
           stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
           stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
       }
   }
```

I've been trying to change the buttons sizes programmatically:

```
tabButton.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)
```

No matter which height or width, or x y position  I set, nothing changes.
Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting a frame directly, use AutoLayout (constraints):

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tabButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    tabButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
])
```

Also, since you are using stack view, setting `x` and `y` values will have no effect since its the sole stack views job to layout these views in appropriate places. Since you are using `spacing` in your stack view, there is no point in setting width constraint so you should be good with adjusting this value, and using only height constraint.

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tabButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
])
```